# How can I clean my newly acquired (used) climbing shoes in order to avoid athlete's foot?

Tags: rock-climbing, cleaning, climbing-shoes

I've been climbing for a few months and my gym sells old rental shoes at a discounted rate. I bought some as a cheap way to get started. I always wear socks when I climb but I've noticed the majority of people don't and I read that it's a bad idea to go sockless with rental shoes because of athlete's foot and such.

I'd love to see what all the rage is about climbing without socks, but want to know if there's a way I can clean my "new" shoes first in order to avoid athlete's foot and all the other fun stuff.

Comment: Also, closely related: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1859/why-go-without-socks-with-climbing-shoes

Comment: I think this question is more geared towards avoiding any skin infections, while the others is about general stink (from ones own, healthy feet). So I'd say this question should make that aspect more apparent and then it has merit on its own.

Comment: Why do you think socks will keep you from getting athlete's foot?  [Athlete's foot fungi and infested skin particles and flakes may spread to socks, shoes, clothes, to other people, pets (via petting), bed sheets, bathtubs, showers, sinks, counters, towels, rugs, floors, and carpets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athlete%27s_foot#Transmission)

Answer (score 3):

I would just spray them with [Lysol disinfectant spray](http://www.lysol.com/disinfectant-spray/disinfectant-spray/). That should take the care of both the smell and kill the fungus. This is the quick and simple solution.

You are right that most people don't climb with socks mostly for better control, unless they are using rental shoes, in which case they use socks to avoid athletes foot. We had a whole bunch on [answers on that topic](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1859/why-go-without-socks-with-climbing-shoes?noredirect=1&lq=1) and they answer it quite well.

There is also another [bunch of answers](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3668/how-to-clean-rock-climbing-shoes) on how to clean rock climbing shoes that are also well worth reading.

Comment: I looked at the answers there, clearly some people believe that socks will prevent athletes foot. But that seems highly unlikely [People can contract the disease indirectly by coming into contact with contaminated items (clothes, towels, etc.) or surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athlete%27s_foot#Transmission) even if the fungus stayed on the outside of the sock (I doubt that is the case) it would get on your hands when you took the socks off.

Comment: @JamesJenkins  realistically one of the employees should be spraying the shoes with Lysol every time